# asp.net - Not able to make adaptive payment on paypal

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Since the sandbox have moved from x.com to developer.paypal.com and sandbox.paypal.com, I am not able to test the adaptive payments from my asp.net application. I imported the users and set the same configuration but its giving me Error 540031.

Some blogs says that paypal have yet not migrated adaptive payment, some says that its not available for non-US developers and some says paypal is stopping this service of adaptive payments. Am very confused. Please help in case anyone have recently integrated this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available for non US developers also. Mistake that I was making was that I was not using the same user which created APP for making the request.